# How do I render a file from the electronjs menu to a react element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, ipc

I'm trying to pass an image path from the main process to my App.js. As of now, the issue is that I'm running into is that my canvas element is null: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'drawImage' of null`. I'm not quite sure why. Here is my `App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Grid, Paper, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/";
import Tools from "./Tools.js";
import Dropzone from "./Dropzone.js";
import { createBrowserHistory as createHistory } from "history";
const history = createHistory();

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myCanvas = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    const canvas = this.myCanvas.current;
    window.ipcRenderer.on("upload", (event, img) => {
      canvas.drawImage(img);
    });
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/">
          <Tools />
          <canvas
            id="myCanvas"
            width="600"
            height="400"
            ref={this.myCanvas}
            style={{ border: "1px solid #000000" }}
          ></canvas>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );

  }
}

export default App;
```

I tried using `document.getElementById('myCanvas')` but, after researching, learned that wasn't the proper way to get the element. I still get this null value when using the ref. I assume it's has something to do with the component not yet being loaded in the DOM but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `upload` event listener before the very first render of your component. At this time, `myCanvas` is not yet set (i.e. `myCanvas.current` is `null`).

You should simply create `upload` event listener after making sure `myCanvas` has been set.

To do so, you can use `componentDidMount` :

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myCanvas = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = this.myCanvas.current;
    window.ipcRenderer.on("upload", (event, img) => {
      canvas.drawImage(img);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/">
          <Tools />
          <canvas
            id="myCanvas"
            width="600"
            height="400"
            ref={this.myCanvas}
            style={{ border: "1px solid #000000" }}
          ></canvas>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This solved this issue although I am now realizing that I need to upload the image to the local server for react to display it.